# return results without iteration inside of a foreach

Tags: c#, azure-table-storage

I need to create a `ConnectionInfo` object by loading the connection info from table storage:

```
    public static async Task<ConnectionInfo> LoadConnection(CloudTable cloudTable, string container)
    {
        var filter = TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("container", QueryComparisons.Equal, container);

        foreach (var entity in await cloudTable.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(new TableQuery<SftpServerConnectionsModel>().Where(filter), null))
        {
            return new ConnectionInfo(entity.uri, entity.user, new AuthenticationMethod[]{
            new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(entity.user,entity.password)});
        }
    }
```

**How do I create the ConnectionInfo object and immediately return, rather than continuing to iterate inside of the foreach loop?**

Can we bypass the foreach altogether? I'm always expecting 1 and only 1 result.

Comment: Isn't that what your code does now (i.e. returns when you hit `return`)? What makes you think it isn't? I suspect your real issue is that it doesn't compile - in which case you likely need to return `null` after the `foreach` (in case the loop is never entered). Or use `FirstOrDefault` rather than a `foreach`.

Comment: A tip - if your code fails to compile then **tell us what the compiler error is**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're always expecting 1 and only 1 result, you can just do a [`.Single()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.single?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Single__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__) on the results of `ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync` instead of iterating over them with a `foreach`:

```
public static async Task<ConnectionInfo> LoadConnection(CloudTable cloudTable, string container) 
{ 
    var filter = TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("container", QueryComparisons.Equal, container);

    var entity = (await cloudTable.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(new TableQuery<SftpServerConnectionsModel>().Where(filter), null)).Single();

    return new ConnectionInfo(entity.uri, entity.user, new AuthenticationMethod[] { new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(entity.user,entity.password)});
}
```

---

The `foreach` approach that you currently have will in fact return on the first item of the iteration and will not continue to iterate over any other results after that. However, doing a `.Single()` like this makes the method a bit more clear on what it's expected to do.

Answer (score 1):

Based on "I'm always expecting 1 and only 1 result." Why the looping in the first place?

If the looping must happen, it means the connectionInfo is not set at the first loop which means you need to find out when it is set or instantiated and then stop the loop. Your best bet is checking the entity variable

This is exactly what break is for. Declare the connectionInfo outside of the loop, then once assigned break out of it.

```
ConnectionInfo connectionInfo = null;
foreach (var entity in await cloudTable.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(new TableQuery<SftpServerConnectionsModel>().Where(filter), null))
    {
        connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo(entity.uri, entity.user, new AuthenticationMethod[]{
        new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(entity.user,entity.password)});
        //If entity is not null break out
        break;
    }
```

Another prettier solution is to use the while loop, while with the whole await variable.Any(), then do the same check

Answer (score 1):

If only expecting 1 result then explicitly request it

For example

```
public static async Task<ConnectionInfo> LoadConnection(CloudTable cloudTable, string container) {
    var filter = TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("container", QueryComparisons.Equal, container);
    var query = new TableQuery<SftpServerConnectionsModel>().Where(filter);
    var querySegment = await cloudTable.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(query, null);
    var entity = querySegment.FirstOrDefault();
    if(entity != null) {
        return new ConnectionInfo(entity.uri, entity.user, new AuthenticationMethod[]{
        new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(entity.user,entity.password)});
    }
    return default(ConnectionInfo);
}
```